# open firewall for multiple IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to give the following IPs access t0 post data to mysql installed on VM google cloud (drupal8) i cannot figure out how to write the format correctly. error Invalid IP address or range. Use CIDR notation and enter the lowest IP address in the subnet.

174.129.249.162|65.17.248.|68.71.103.|184.73.155.222|184.72.56.152|184.72.56.199|184.73.192.230|184.169.131.85|52.0.132.63|52.71.25.2|52.71.19.16|52.71.25.60|52.71.25.97|52.11.235.107|52.35.106.209|52.32.146.111|52.25.210.125|52.33.176.145

Answer (score 2):

The format should be 174.129.249.162/32 184.73.155.222/32 etc

Comment: sorry - same error

174.129.249.162/32,
65.17.248/32,
68.71.103/32,
184.73.155.222/32,
184.72.56.152/32,
184.72.56.199/32,
184.73.192.230/32,
184.169.131.85/32,
52.0.132.63/32,
52.71.25.2/32,
52.71.19.16/32,
52.71.25.60/32,
52.71.25.97/32,
52.11.235.107/32,
52.35.106.209/32,
52.32.146.111/32,
52.25.210.125/32,
52.33.176.145/32

Invalid IP address or range. Use CIDR notation and enter the lowest IP address in the subnet.

Comment: i got it working. just needed to enter them one by one :-) thanks for the help (y)